# How do I trigger an onClick event when a finger goes outside the button in the screen during long click

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener, onlongclicklistener, android-event

```
  public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) { 
         Toast.makeText(getContext(), "long click",
                         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return false;  }

    public void onClick(View arg0) { 
       Toast.makeText(getContext(), "click",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
```

If I return `false` in `onLongClick()` function, the `onClick()` function will be called.

But, while moving a finger over across the screen during the long press
time, `onClick()` event not triggered when the finger goes outside the
button in the screen. Does anyone know how to handle this case? I want to
trigger an `onClick()` event when the finger goes outside the button in
the screen.